# Data.table package is not working even after installing the package in Rstudio. How it can be fixed?

Tags: r, data.table, r-package

```r
> install.packages("data.table")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
           binary source needs_compilation
data.table 1.13.6 1.14.0              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) 
installing the source package ‘data.table’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/data.table_1.14.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5303849 bytes (5.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
*** pkg-config is not installed.
*** Compilation will now be attempted and if it works you can ignore this message. In
*** particular, this should be the case on Mac where zlib is built in or pkg-config
*** is not installed. However, if compilation fails, try 'locate zlib.h zconf.h' and
*** ensure the zlib development library is installed :
***   deb: zlib1g-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
***   rpm: zlib-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
***   There is a zlib in brew for OSX but the built in zlib should work.
*** Note that zlib is required to compile R itself so you may find the advice in the R-admin
*** guide helpful regarding zlib. On Debian/Ubuntu, zlib1g-dev is a dependency of r-base as
*** shown by 'apt-cache showsrc r-base | grep ^Build-Depends | grep zlib', and therefore
*** 'sudo apt-get build-dep r-base' should be sufficient too.
*** To silence this message, please ensure that :
***   1) 'pkg-config --exists zlib' succeeds (i.e. $? -eq 0)
***   2) 'pkg-config --libs zlib' contains -lz
*** Compilation will now be attempted ...
./configure: line 91: -fopenmp: command not found
*** OpenMP not supported! data.table uses OpenMP to automatically
***   parallelize operations like sorting, grouping, file reading, etc.
*** For details on how to install the necessary toolchains on your OS see:
***   https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation
*** Continuing installation without OpenMP support...
*** Compilation without compression support in fwrite
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/data.table’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/pn/3jvffq0x5yx28m8rhbgwp0n80000gn/T/RtmpB2XTYQ/downloaded_packages’
> library(data.table)
Error in library(data.table) : there is no package called ‘data.table’
```

Comment: Hi ChatlotteSoe, welcome to SO. It looks like your error message is quite informative here: there is a library called xcrun that this package depends on, and it's either not on your machine or not in your PATH. I'd follow the steps recommended in that error message and see if you can't resolve the issue. 

As a quick note, you did _not_ successfully install data.table, that's what that "non-zero exit status" warning is telling you, this is a package installation issue.

Comment: does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321858/xcrun-missing-installing-xcode-command-line-tools-not-fixing-issue

Comment: @Michael actually I don't know what `xcrun` is, `data.table` shouldn't depend on it _per se_. On Mac, there have been a lot of `data.table` installation issues, can you check our [Installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) which has a lot of helpful tips, as well as our [issue tracker](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues?q=is%3Aissue+install+mac+is%3Aclosed) which has a slew of related issues for installing on Mac.

Comment: Thanks @Michael but yes, I have tried installing data.table package from Library (CRUN) but still even after installing the package, it is not working as it shows there is no package called ‘data.table’ when I called library(data.frame). That is why. :'(

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChirico yes, you are right. I have been working on Mac, and I have checked the one you shared and tried it already but still didn't work as well.

Comment: @Chatlotte you can try opening an issue on the bug tracker, it might get some visibility from other Mac users who could help

Comment: @MichaelChirico you know it was my bad. I know why it didn't not work. Just simply I didn't put "" when I installed it. instead of writing install.package(data.table) rather I wrote like install.package("data.table"). Careless me. for that reason, it showed error. :D